# Yodlee daily refresh

Tags: yodlee

Let's say I want to do a daily pull in of transactions on all my user accounts.

Do I need to manually trigger refreshes every day with startSiteRefresh or will Yodlee anyway do daily refreshes and all I need to use is executeUserSearchRequest alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yodlee refreshes the user accounts everyday and recommend you **not to** refresh the user's accounts as a back end service(when user is not logged in), while you can refresh user's account when user log in to your application and want to see refreshed/latest data.

Using executeUserSearchReqeust will pull the transactions from Yodlee data base to your application and won't trigger any refresh.

Comment: But how would you refresh when they log back in?

Comment: @socca1157 - You could provide a link or button for the users to refresh their accounts in case if they are seeing stale data, and at the back end you can trigger a refresh for that specific accounts of user.

Comment: @Apoorv are you familiar with the Yodlee ["Data Extract Procedures" best practices](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Extract_Procedures)? It says to call the Refresh API (getRefreshedUserItems) in a loop every minute.  Can you please help me understand why that page suggests calling the API every minute but this post suggests otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinZych- getRefreshedUserItems API doesn't refresh the item. It will fetch you the items which got refreshed during the mentioned duration(which Yodlee recommend to keep as 1-5 mins, so you'll get less number of items and process it quickly/easily). While here it is mentioned to refresh user using startSiteRefresh API.